# Shell_exec with path, command option and variable

Tags: php, windows, variables, exe, shell-exec

I'm new to php. In my php file, I have this command :

```
shell_exec("\"C:\path_with_spaces_to_.exe\" -c -n 1 C:\path_to_image\$image_name 2>&1");
```

Weird thing is my `$image_name` is never getting read.
I believe maybe I miss some fundamental things.
I tried many ways, but It's been 3 hours here and still stuck.

Any suggestion about what mistake do I have here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have to escape `\` other wise it will escape `$`. Try this solution:

```
echo("\"C:\path_with_spaces_to_.exe\" -c -n 1 C:\path_to_image\\$image_name 2>&1");
```

Comment: For other people, who had the same problem, there is another solution I found. But, @B. Desai answer still neater. Here is another solution for it using dot (.): `shell_exec('"C::\path_with_spaces_to_.exe\" -c -n 1 C:/path_to_image/' . $image_name . ' 2>&1')`